# Embedded Google form doesn't work on some browsers

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, google-forms

I have embedded a Google form in a webpage. It works correctly with Google Chrome and Safari but when using Internet Explorer or Firefox, upon clicking the submit button, a message asking if the user wishes the leave the page appears and the submission does not go through. Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: what version of IE and Firefox were you using?

Comment: It was IE11 and I think the latest version of Firefox